# Subquery in django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a table with next columns:

- key
- time
- value

And I need to have a query like that:

```
SELECT
  "time",
  SUM("value")
FROM (
  SELECT
    "key",
    django_trunc_datetime("time"),
    AVG("value")
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY "key", django_trunc_datetime("time")
)
GROUP BY "time"
```

Is it possible in Django ORM? Maybe with some fake model based on the subquery?

Thanks

**UPDATED:**
Looks like I have to create five database views (because there are Hour/Day/Week/Month/Year arguments for the django_trunc_datetime) but it can have a bad performance because in this case, I can't do the previous filtering. :(

I also thought about SQLAlchemy but it doesn't have universal datetime truncate function

**SOLUTION**

**The solution with DjangoORM (not completed solution but illustrate the idea)**

```
class TheApp(models.Model):
    a = models.DateTimeField()
    b = models.IntegerField()

class B(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed = False

    c = models.DateTimeField()
    d = models.IntegerField()

TheApp.objects.create(a=datetime.now(), b=4)
TheApp.objects.create(a=datetime.now(), b=5)
TheApp.objects.create(a=datetime.now(), b=7)

q1 = TheApp.objects.annotate(c=F('b'), d=Max('a')).values('c', 'd', 'id').query
q1.group_by = ('c',)
q2 = B.objects.annotate(a=F('c') * 2, b=Max('d')).values('a', 'b', 'id').query
q2.group_by = ('a',)

q3 = str(q2).replace('theapp_b', 'sub').replace('FROM "sub" ', f'FROM ({q1}) AS "sub" ')
print(q3)
print(list(B.objects.raw(q3)))
```

**The solution I have chosen:**

Use SQLAlchemy via `aldjemy`

Comment: [Subquery expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)

Comment: @DanielRoseman how can you do a query like this (where subquery is in the `from` clause) with Subquery()? I thought it is usable only with `annotate` which adds a subquery returning some values to `select` clause. I would really appreciate some example, as I was struggling too with this to overcome issue of mixing window functions and filtering